# How to subtract two different date formats to get days in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix

I am working on bash. I have to subtract current date from a given date to get number of days as a difference. The given date is in format *m/d/yyyy* so instead of **09/26/2015** it is **9/26/2015**. So even if I try to convert both dates into same format and subtract it says invalid date format.

```
           date1=$(date +"%F")
           date2=$(date -d 11/2/2015 +"%F")
           diff=$(date "--date=${date2} -${date1}" +%F)
           echo $diff days remaining
```

This is what I had tried with some variations, but doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked `date` 's man page before you tried `date "--date=${date2} -${date1}" +%F` ? or you made a patch?

Comment: I have checked the man page. I have tried converting them using %s and dividing by 86400 but that too doesn't work because instead m/d/yyyy it reads date as d/m/yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let diff=(`date +%s -d 11/2/2015` - `date +%s`)/86400
echo $diff days remaining
```

Comment: This code works fine. But how do i convert 11/2/2015 to 20151102 as the given date i am reading from file.

Answer (score 2):

there are two problems: converting the user-provided date into a normalized form and calculcating the difference in days.

### normalizing date

how date interprets a date-string depends on the current locale.
Try to find a locale that uses your special formatting (`%m/%d/%Y`):

```
$ LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 date -d 1/2/2015
Fri Jan  2 00:00:00 CET 2015
```

### calculating the difference

bash only can only do integer arithmetic, so convert your date first to some integer representation, do the subtraction and convert the representation to days (if needed).

```
$ LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 \
  echo $(( ( $(date -d 11/2/2015 +%s) - $(date +%s)) / (3600*24) ))
32
```

This uses `$(...)` instead of `...` to function substitution.
It also uses `$(( ... ))` for evalution of math expression instead of the bashism `let x=()`, so you can use it in POSIX-conformant shell-scripts (e.g. interpreted by */bin/dash*)